# Issue with hibernate bidirectional OneToMany relation

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I have set bidirectional OneToMany relation between two entities as given below.

**Test1 entity**

```
@Entity
public class Test1 {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "test1")
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Test2.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Test2> test2;
}
```

**Test2 Entity**

```
@Entity
public class Test2 {

    @EmbeddedId
    private Test2Pk testPk;
    private String name;
}
```

**Test2Pk entity**

```
@Embeddable
public class Test2Pk implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @JoinColumn(name="test1")
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Test1.class)
    private Test1 test1;

    private Integer row;
}
```

Insert operation is working without any problems. But when I try to update the data I get the following exception.

*org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper$StandardWarningHandler logWarning
WARN: Column 'test1' cannot be null*

I checked on debug mode and I can see all the values are set to the entity.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Well, If I have understood this correctly, I see some problem with this setup. Instead of JoinColumn annotation on "List<Test2> test2" in Test1  entity, there must be a mappedBy attribute in OneToMany declaration, which should refer the "testPk.test1" property of Test2 entity.

Comment: Avoid using JoinColumn annotation on both side , using JoinColumn annotation  on child side which  indicates foreign key for child table. Which entity you were triying to update ?

Comment: This link will help you definitly : https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany#Unidirectional_OneToMany.2C_No_Inverse_ManyToOne.2C_No_Join_Table_.28JPA_2.0_ONLY.29

Comment: @UdayFokane thanks man. That worked for me.